# Pandas DataFrame.merge MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

### Goal

My goal is to merge two DataFrames by their common column (gene names) so I can take a product of each gene score across each gene row.  I'd then perform a `groupby` on patients and cells and sum all scores from each.  The ultimate data frame should look like this:

```
    patient  cell 
    Pat_1    22RV1    12
             DU145    15
             LN18      9
    Pat_2    22RV1    12
             DU145    15
             LN18      9
    Pat_3    22RV1    12
             DU145    15
             LN18      9
```

That last part should work fine, but I have not been able to perform the first merge on gene names due to a `MemoryError`.  Below are snippets of each DataFrame.

### Data

cell_s =

```
    Description          Name                      level_2  0
0  LOC100009676  100009676_at  LN18_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM  1
1  LOC100009676  100009676_at               22RV1_PROSTATE  2
2  LOC100009676  100009676_at               DU145_PROSTATE  3
3          AKT3      10000_at  LN18_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM  4
4          AKT3      10000_at               22RV1_PROSTATE  5
5          AKT3      10000_at               DU145_PROSTATE  6
6          MED6      10001_at  LN18_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM  7
7          MED6      10001_at               22RV1_PROSTATE  8
8          MED6      10001_at               DU145_PROSTATE  9
```

cell_s is about 10,000,000 rows

patient_s =

```
             id level_1  0
0          MED6   Pat_1  1
1          MED6   Pat_2  1
2          MED6   Pat_3  1
3  LOC100009676   Pat_1  2
4  LOC100009676   Pat_2  2
5  LOC100009676   Pat_3  2
6          ABCD   Pat_1  3
7          ABCD   Pat_2  3
8          ABCD   Pat_3  3
    ....
```

patient_s is about 1,200,000 rows

### Code

```
def get_score(cell, patient):
    cell_s = cell.set_index(['Description', 'Name']).stack().reset_index()
    cell_s.columns = ['Description', 'Name', 'cell', 's1']

    patient_s = patient.set_index('id').stack().reset_index()
    patient_s.columns = ['id', 'patient', 's2']

    # fails here:
    merged = cell_s.merge(patient_s, left_on='Description', right_on='id')
    merged['score'] = merged.s1 * merged.s2

    scores = merged.groupby(['patient','cell'])['score'].sum()
    return scores
```

I was getting a MemoryError when initially `read_csv`ing these files, but then specifying the dtypes resolved the issue.  Confirming that my [python is 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205005/pandas-memory-error) did not fix my issue either.  I haven't reached the limitations on pandas, have I?

Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| Pandas 0.16.2

Comment: You might save quite a bit of memory by converting strings to categoricals if you  haven't already.  I don't believe 64-bit pandas will have any memory limitations other than what your computer has.

Comment: When importing with 'read_csv', I set the 'dtype='category' for all columns containing strings, I get `TypeError: data type "category" not understood`.  I guess because [Categorical is not a numpy array](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html#categorical-is-not-a-numpy-array).  Can you think of a work around? Can I simply ignore the MemoryError?

Comment: I think you have to convert after reading in.  I usu do something like `df['x'] = df['x'].astype('category')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider two workarounds:

**CSV By CHUNKS**

Apparently, [read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622652/large-persistent-dataframe-in-pandas) can suffer performance issues and therefore large files must load in iterated chunks.

```
cellsfilepath = 'C:\\Path\To\Cells\CSVFile.csv'
tp = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(cellsfilepath, sep=',', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
cell_s = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)

patientsfilepath = 'C:\\Path\To\Patients\CSVFile.csv'
tp = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(patientsfilepath, sep=',', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
patient_s = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
```

**CSV VIA SQL**

As a database guy, I always recommend handling large data loads and merging/joining with a SQL relational engine that scales well for such processes. I have written many a comment on dataframe merge Q/As to this effect -even in R. You can use any SQL database including file server dbs (Access, SQLite) or client server dbs (MySQL, MSSQL, or other), even where your dfs derive. Python maintains a built-in library for SQLite (otherwise you use ODBC); and dataframes can be pushed into databases as tables using [pandas to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
import sqlite3

dbfile = 'C:\\Path\To\SQlitedb.sqlite'
cxn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
c = cxn.cursor()

cells_s.to_sql(name='cell_s', con = cxn, if_exists='replace')
patient_s.to_sql(name='patient_s', con = cxn, if_exists='replace')

strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM cell_s c INNER JOIN patient_s p ON c.Description = p.id;'
# MIGHT HAVE TO ADJUST ABOVE FOR CELL AND PATIENT PARAMS IN DEFINED FUNCTION

merged = pd.read_sql(strSQL, cxn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the two work arounds.  I started running `read_csv` in chunks, and it appears to reduce the memory usage (though I haven't measured exactly).  The SQL solution looks like "the way", but when I run the above code, it throws an  attribute error of `'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'cursor'` at `cells_s.to_sql`.  I located the issue to line 1467 of `pandas/io/sql.py` , in execute
`cur = self.con.cursor()`.  Checked the docs and SO, and couldn't determine the cause of the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: I eliminated the `c = conn.cursor()` following an example from [Sebastian Raschka](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622652/large-persistent-dataframe-in-pandas/28371706#28371706).  Seems to work for my merge, but I [wouldn't be able to query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318126/why-do-you-need-to-create-a-cursor-when-querying-a-sqlite-database) my new database, correct?

Comment: First issue is due to me using the cursor object in `con` argument of `to_sql()` and not the connection object. I made the edit with a new variable, `cxn`. Yes, you should be able to query db using [cursor's execute()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) with fetchall() that outputs in list format. But do note in above, query results are being passed into a pandas df using [read_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html).

Comment: It should not be necessary to do a workaround. Pandas should be able to handle this. Has anybody reported that issue to pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do it in pieces, or look into blaze. http://blaze.pydata.org